# I am trying to pass value from controller to view page but it shows my controller is receiving null value, even though I'm passing it in the link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to execute the controller by accepting the value in "val". Through "ID" I am trying to fetch  exact Data from Database. Then I am passing the retrieve data to my view page in order to show the proper data values with their respecting names defined in Modal class.

This is the error my webpage is displaying after choosing "User Details"

[Page view before clicking User Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj5lf.jpg)

[Page view after clicking User Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuuWr.png)

I'm receiving following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'val' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UserDetails(Int32)' in 'OfficeWork.Controllers.PopulationsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
> Parameter name: parameters

Code Home Page controller:

```
private PopulationDBContext db = new PopulationDBContext();

public ActionResult HomePage(int? id)
{
    Population population = db.Populations.Find(id);
    return View(population);
}
```

Code of UserDetails Page controller:

```
private PopulationDBContext db = new PopulationDBContext();
public ActionResult UserDetails(int val)
{
    var std = db.Populations.Where(s => s.ID == val).FirstOrDefault();      
    return View(std);
}
```

Model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace OfficeWork.Models
{
    public class Population
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name ="Email")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Enter valid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number")]
        [Required]
        public long MobileNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [Required]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class PopulationDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Population> Populations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomePage.cshtml

```
@model OfficeWork.Models.Population
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HomePage";
}
@{
    var value = Model.ID;
}

@section navbar{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <P class="navbar-brand">PROJECT</P>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active" style="cursor:pointer;"><a>Home</a></li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Details", "UserDetails/"+value, new { controller = "Populations" }, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "cursor:pointer;" })</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Log Out", "SignIn", "populations", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user" })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}

<br />
<br />
<div class="container">
    <img src="~/Images/forestbridge.jpg" alt="Notebook" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="centered">Coming Soon...</div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Hello There!</h1>
        <p>While it’s difficult to be entirely optimistic in this unprecedented times, we must believe, life is short, but it is wide.“this too shall pass”.</p>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.Hidden("studentIdVal", @value);
```

UserDetails.cshtml

```
@model OfficeWork.Models.Population

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
}

@{
    var value = Model.ID;
}

@*Nav bar to direct user to Log Out page(Log In Page)*@

@section navbar{
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <P class="navbar-brand">PROJECT</P>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "HomePage/" + value, new { controller = "Populations" }, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "cursor:pointer;" })</li>
            <li class="active" style="cursor:pointer;"><a>User Details</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(" Log Out", "SignIn", "populations", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-user" })</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}

<div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <h4>User Details</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<p>
</p>
```

Comment: I would use the following overload of ActionLink: `@Html.ActionLink("User Details", "UserDetails", "Populations", new { val = value }, new { @style = "cursor:pointer;" })`

Comment: This just worked fine. Thank You!

Comment: This post need more details.

Comment: By the way, how did it just avoided the null value? I was added "+value" in my ActionLink

Comment: I have added an answer with more explanation, please accept if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect overload of LinkExtensions.ActionLink

The overload that you should be using is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Web_Routing_RouteValueDictionary_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__), i.e.

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeValues, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> htmlAttributes);
```

So your code should be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User Details", "UserDetails", "Populations", new { val = value }, new { @style = "cursor:pointer;" })
```

You can verify yourself with intellisense which overload you area actually using, but I suspect it is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) one, i.e.:

```
public static System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString ActionLink (this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes);
```

So the { controller = "Populations" } is being interpereted as the route values. You want to be passing { val = value } as the route values.